# Configuring Arduino1.6 on Windows 8.1 to flash Attiny85 via USBTinyISP

Tags: windows

I'd appreciate some guidance on how to do the above.

On running Arduino 1.6 on Windows and clicking on Tools, I've selected 'USBTinyISP' as the Programmer but cannot work out how to configure Arduino 1.6 to include Attiny85 as a Board, assuming that's what I have to do.

Comment: Eventually figured I'd made so many changes based on articles I'd read on the Internet, it would be best to start agin from scratch.

Comment: Eventually figured I'd made so many changes based on articles I'd read on the Internet, it would be best to start again from scratch. Uninstalled then reinstalled Arduino1.6 then followed precisely the instruction given for Programming an Attiny with Arduino 1.6 found here http://highlowtech.org/?p=1695. Bingo; Attiny boards were now in the list and all worked perfectly. Thanks for replying. Hope someone else finds this useful.

Comment: Then I suggest you add the solution as an answer to your own question, for others to be helpful.

Comment: I thought i had added what I'd done to answer my own question.

Comment: As an answer (down the page) is the way to go!